# Group and summarize across mulitple mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, sum

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for this scenario.
I have multiple databases, and I want to summarize them on a column. Either just one database, or all or any given number in between.
The stores (databases) are given by a php array.

Is it best practice to run each databases queries in a php loop and add the values by php? I have started to do this as seen below.

Note that the query below works perfect for **one** database, the join is just another table on that database.

The query and php function I have so far is this

```
function getPeriodDateTransactions ($database, $date, $date2, array $stores) {

$username = 'root';
$password = '***';

foreach ($stores as $store_db){

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$store_db;
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); 

$statement = $db->prepare("
SELECT tr.SoldDate, SUM(tr.TotalAmount) - IFNULL(rebuy.RebuySum, 0) as SumByReceipt,
COUNT(DISTINCT(tr.`ForsNr`)) as TotalCustomers, IFNULL(rebuy.RebuySum, 0) RebuySum
FROM transactions tr   
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT SoldDate, SUM(TotalAmount) as RebuySum
FROM transactions_rebuy
WHERE SoldDate BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date2'
GROUP BY SoldDate
) as rebuy
ON tr.SoldDate= rebuy.SoldDate
WHERE tr.SoldDateBETWEEN '$date' AND '$date2' 
GROUP by tr.SoldDate
ORDER by tr.SoldDate DESC");

$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

return json_encode($row, TRUE);

}
```

Most grateful for your input on this.

To clarify, I want the exact same result as for one database but with all the sums added (summarized) for every DB

Comment: If you want to summarize - then summarize. Do no return only the last one

Comment: Ok, so best practise and performance is to summarize the databases results by PHP?

Comment: The best practice apparently is to work with just a single database.